# Deleting rows by specific Datetime (stored as webkit timestamp)

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]Hi I'm new to software development and need some advice with SQL got access to a database in which the amount of customers of a shop is stored. The problem is that the sensors have been damaged and counted way too much customers. Thus I want (after fixing those) to delete all rows in that specific table which aren't necessary. In short words I want the table to only contain rows on times like [hour 0-23]:00 OR [hour 0-23]:15 OR [hour 0-23]:30 OR [hour 0-23]:45 - so like 24/7 every 15mins of an hour.

I'm accessing the database through the SQL CompactView (latest Version from Sourceforge) and tried some SQL queries. I guess I'll have to do something like the code below.
Additionally it seems to be that I have to use "[ ]" in which I write my table I'm using (eg. SELECT timestamp FROM [customers\15mins]). Seems strange because I couldn't find SQL articles mentioning "[]". Is this a .NET Framework thing?
One last thing I'm not allowed to change anything in the schema (eg. use unix timestamp instead of webkittimestamp)

//This SQL query bounces around in my head

DELETE * FROM [customers\15min]
WHERE NOT(webkittimestamp = hour:00 OR hour:15 OR hour:30 OR hour:45)

The picture shows the timestamp column and one column for every gate of the building which counts visitors

Comment: The [] are because you've got a \ in the table name...

Comment: Thank you for that advice! I was thinking about that, because I got an error referencing the "\". But as I'm not allowed to change the schema because of other references I figured out that it magically works with []. Now I know why :D

Comment: @newbiedude . . . Edit your question and show sample data and explain the data types.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
DELETE c FROM [customers\15min] c
    WHERE datepart(minute, webkittimestamp) not in (0, 15, 30, 45);
```

Note:  This does not take the seconds into account.  I don't know if that is important.

Comment: thank you for this suggestion the seconds aren't so important - only the minutes. I can tell you if it works in a few hours :) btw what does the c at the end of the first line stand for?

Comment: @newbiedude . . . It is a table alias.

Comment: I tried it out but it gives me an error although I think your solution is what I'm looking for. The error is "An overflow might have occurred while converting bigint to datetime". Guess the webkittimestamp column is stored as bigint and not as date or a similar datatype

Comment: @newbiedude . . . Well, your question makes no mention of that little detail.  You need to either convert to a `datetime` to use date/time functions or explain what the format is.

Comment: the customers\15min table contains a column called timestamp in which timestamps are stored in the webkit format (I've found a converter online https://www.epochconverter.com/webkit). What I'd like to achieve is to delete all rows in which the timestamp isnt' at minute 15, 30, 45 or 00 of an hour. The main problem is that a webkit timestamp looks something like `13194311689000000` and I don't know how to get from this number to a value which I could compare to 15,30,45 or 00 in SQL